# string value should be incremented by 1

Tags: sql-server-2008

the  shown code is not incrementing by 1, same string value is displaying for all records .

```
DECLARE @q_id  NVARCHAR(50)
begin 

SET @q_id='JEE_PHY_1' 

UPDATE oems_question7  SET q_id = SUBSTRING (@q_id ,0,CHARINDEX('_', @q_id,5) + 1 ) + ' ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING ( @q_id ,CHARINDEX('_', @q_id,5) + 1, LEN(@q_id) )) +1)
WHERE id between 1 and 40

end
```

Comment: An `UPDATE` applies (effectively) to all rows, as a set, at the same time. It's not defined to apply to one row at a time. This means that all of the values on the right hand side of assignments in the `SET` clause need to be computable in parallel. Can you give us an example of the data set that you want to apply the change to and the expected end result?

Answer (score 1):

With your code you are updating all rows with exactly the same value. You should apply ROW_NUMBER to give each row a distinct increasing number and then update the rows.

```
DECLARE @q_id  NVARCHAR(50)
begin 

SET @q_id='JEE_PHY_1' 

;WITH UpdateCTE AS
(
    SELECT q_id,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY q_id) AS RowNum
    FROM   oems_question7 
    WHERE  id between 1 and 40
)
UPDATE UpdateCTE   
SET q_id = SUBSTRING (@q_id ,0,CHARINDEX('_', @q_id,5) + 1 ) + ' ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,RowNum)


end
```

Comment: You can't have `ROW_NUMBER` without an `OVER` clause.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So very true...It is still too early in the morning here...